# Powershell: Converting JSON to CSV

Tags: json

We have a web-JSON and we managed to download locally.
Now, we would like to convert that JSON to a simple .CSV
I read several tutorials but can't find a way to solve my problem.

**This is an example of my JSON (simple stock information):**
[{"Number":"A010","Stock":167,"BackInStockDate":null},{"Number":"A011","Stock":9,"BackInStockDate":null},....]

**If I use**

```
((Get-Content -Path C:\Lagerbestandsabgleich\gastronoble.json) | ConvertFrom-Json).results |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    Set-Content C:\Lagerbestandsabgleich\gastronoble.csv
```

I receive the following error message:

```
ConvertTo-Csv : Das Argument kann nicht an den Parameter "InputObject" gebunden werden, da es NULL ist.
In Zeile:2 Zeichen:5
+     ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToCsvCommand
```

What is wrong?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: For a relatively simple JSON object like yours, why not just use an online JSON -> CSV converter? They work pretty well and are fast.

Comment: I need to run it as a job to update a database. Therefore I need the updated .CSV on my local.